# Sharepoint 2010 Item Opened Event Receiver

Tags: event-handlers

I need to detect when a user opens a document in a specified list, and log their view in another list, however I see no method in SPItemEventReceiver for detecting such an event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver_methods.aspx

Am I looking in the wrong place, or does this functionality not exist?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess if it doesn't, one workaround would be to write a user control and add it to the view page. When the view page is hit, I can record the hit...

Answer (score 1):

A user control is not going to track a document being opened. You may want to have a look at SharePoint's internal auditing facility to track if a document has been opened, then create a job to periodically process new 'open' events.

As you say, there is no 'open event handler' in SharePoint, which is a great shame.

Comment: My plan was to use the user control to detect when a document is opened, then write the code to add the open event to another list.

Is this what you mean when you refer to a SP job? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: That is what I meant with 'a job'. How are you planning on detecting a document being opened using a user control?